422 error when posting list[str] to a FastAPI endpoint
I'm using FastAPI v0.111.0, pydantic v2.0.0
I've got the following class
class Index(File):
    indexes: list[str] | None = Field(default_factory=list, description="List of indexes")

class File:
   id: str = Field("", description="poc id")


My router is
approuter.post("/router")
async def test(data: Index = Depends()):
    try:
        return {"message": f"Success"}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e)

// rest of the code
I'm sending the following json using the vscode rest client
POST localhost:5001/router
Content-Type: application/json

{
"indexes":["Test1", "Test2"]
"id": "1"
}

However, i'm getting "Input should be a valid list" error and getting a 422 error in response.
I've tried a few different ways of sending the json data but to no avail. I was expecting to be able to POST the json body and hit my router Any help would be massively appreciated.
I've read through Pydantic 2: "Input should be a valid list" but i'm just posting body data so i'm not 100% sure if that question is similiar.

It's not obvious how or if the value of the indexes key, rather than the entire JSON object, is being passed to upload_file.

updated to hopefully provide some more info. My thoughts are the entire json object is passed but i think it's a valid object

You're missing , after your list in the JSON object in your request example.
